# Navigate to contact's profile

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to open the default windows phone contact's profile out of my own app.
I use the following code to receive all contacts:

```
Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
contacts.SearchCompleted += HandleContactsSearchCompleted;
contacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
```

The `HandleContactsSearchCompleted` method iterates over all contacts, performs some filtering and displays them.
On click on a contact (instance of `Contact` from the list of contacts received through the `SeachCompleted` event) I want to open the standard profile which I also see when I click on a contact in my people hub.

Is there a special `Uri` to use with the `NavigationService.Navigate` method or a particular task for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to invoke the native contact profile page for a contact. But, since you have the contact object with all the necessary details, you could implement a profile page of your own.

Comment: Of course I could, but I want to show all informations including tweets, the current status and all other linked social profiles. That is a lot of work for a simple view that already exists. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the Windows Phone SDK does not provide a method for showing the contact card of an existing contact in your address book.